# Winforms WebBrowser set maximum content width

Tags: c#, html, css, winforms

Is there a way to force WebBrowser somewhat like maximum content width? I'd like to display html content ( it's all just styled text ) with no horizontal scrolling, only vertical. So let's say for a message `This is a test message, that has no other purpose`

```
This is a test
message, that
has no other
purpose
```

would be display, width vertical scrollbar being showen if needed.

Comment: have you looked at mdsn? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser(v=vs.110).aspx there is a width property that you can set to your screen/form's width

Comment: Add the CSS as needed? `wb.Document.Body.Style = "overflow-y:scroll;";` ?

Comment: @jbutler483 All I could find was the control's dimensions, am I missing something?

Comment: @AlexK. The scrollbar won't show with `ScrollBarsEnabled` being set to false. And with the property being set to true, the x-axis is visible.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding you, could you possilby clarify the question? I was understanding that you wanted to stretch the control?

Comment: @AlexK. Nevermind, I thought `none` was the `overflow-x` style I was looking for, but it was `hidden`. Can you turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @jbutler483 I was trying "ignore" horizontal overflow and show only the vertical scrollbar if needed. Settings document styles as suggested by Alex did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The WebBrowser supports some CSS style properties, which you can insert as an inline style in the `<head>` section of your content. The one you want is `width`; set this to a percentage (probably somewhere between 90-100) in a default class for the body and an explicit class for any img tags that you can determine to be of sufficient size (how you do that depends on the content; some images are named with their native dimensions, or the width property might be set in the tag to help improve rendering speed; if all else fails you can use the `WebBrowser.Document` property to access DOM elements by ID and get their attributes), and the content will resize to fit the width of your WebBrowser control.

However, there is a caveat. The WebBrowser's default renderer (based on IE v6.1) does not support the `max-width` property (first fully supported in IE 7 according to W3schools' documentation). This would be the preferable option instead of `width`, because it tells the browser to resize smaller if necessary to fit, but won't force the images larger than actual size the way `width: X%` will. No matter what your threshold for "significant size" is, there is an image just under that bar that will cause horizontal scrolling headaches at small window sizes because it doesn't resize, and an image just above that bar that will look ludicrous at large window sizes because it does resize.

There is a way to force IE to use a more modern renderer on an application-by-application basis through the Windows Registry, but it's kind of a pain, as Registry changes require elevated user permissions which trigger UAC prompts (and your end user might not have administrative permissions). It's best to have an installer with some custom actions to do it for you at install-time, or if you're in corporate America, have an admin push a registry script via Group Policy (it's the same value for the same key on any computer).

To make images behave in a similar way as the max-width property at runtime without admin permissions, you can prepend some HTML into the head of your content, that imports JQuery from some stable web source and defines a resize event handler for the document. This event should query for all images in the document and use their `naturalHeight` and `naturalWidth` (representing each image's original size) and their parent's width to set their size to either an aspect-correct best-fit, or to the "natural" dimensions, whichever is smaller.

Which solution is less work depends on how big a deal putting the right code in the right places ends up being, versus how big a deal getting registry changes made is.